# trying to enable monitor mode in Raspbian

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, sniffing, raspbian

I followed [this](https://github.com/seemoo-lab/nexmon) tutorial in order to enable monitor mode in my Raspberry Pi 3, when I get to the step where I have to create the monitor interface, I've got the following error:

```
iw phy iw dev wlan0 info | gawk '/wiphy/ {printf "phy" $2}' interface add mon0 type monitor

command Failed: Operation not supported (-95)
```

Has anyone tried this or another method to enable monitor mode in the Pi? I don't want to change the OS to Kali because I'm using that Pi for more projects.

Also, I've tried connecting different USB wireless adapters but the Pi doesn't detect them as a new wireless interface.

Comment: And the OS you're actually using? All we no so far is that you don't want to use Kali...

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I'm using Raspbian, it's in the title of the question :)